# Partitioning in Ubuntu VM

Tags: partitioning, virtualbox

Well, it's my 1st time to install Ubuntu, and I have installed it via VirtualBox on a host system of MS Windows 7.

On Partitioning, I'm asked to choose if the partitioning is manually set or guided, and set to the whole drive. I couldn't manage it manually, and I have some doubts.

If I choose the whole drive option, will it lead to formatting partitions on my host system?

How will the partitioning allocate the space required on the hard disk while being virtual?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you choose "the whole drive option" when installing Ubuntu on the virtual machine, it will not interfere with partitions on the physical drive of your host.

The guest operating system's "whole drive" will be confined to the virtual disk file, stored on your host in a file with `.vdi` extension (along with some other configuration files for the virtual machine, by default inside your user home directory `VirtualBox VMs` subfolder).

By default VirtualBox creates an empty file which will grow as the guest OS writes changes. It is possible to change the settings to allocate full size of the virtual disk at once.

As for the partitioning inside the VM, you should be fine with the defaults suggested by Ubuntu.